# Inconsistent capitalisation of "Frequent" under the question tab selector (mobile theme)

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design, font

When viewing the mobile theme, the capitalisation of "Frequent" under the question tab selector is inconsistent with the other menu options.

[image: screenshot]

It should instead be uncapitalised: "frequent".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next build out.

Comment: Thank you. This had been bugging me for a while.